Power BI DAX Function
This is my data in Yardi :

Rank represents unique line no. for each GL code.
This is the matrix I created :

Now I want to calculate % which has logic mentioned below.
All the amount should be divided by amount of line no. 24 (Total Actual income)
It should look like below image :

But instead it is giving me infinity error for all other line and giving correct % for line no. 24.
This is the dax functino I used.
PercentageMeasure = VAR TotalSelectedAmount = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Onepage[Amount]),
        ALLSELECTED(Onepage[Property Code])
    )
    var TotalActualIncome =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Onepage[Amount]),ALLSELECTED(Onepage[Property Code]), FILTER(Onepage, Onepage[Property Code] IN VALUES(Onepage[Property Code]) && Onepage[Month] in VALUES(Onepage[Month]) && Onepage[Year] in VALUES(Onepage[Year]) && Onepage[Rank] = 24)
    )
    RETURN 
    ([Total Selected Amount]*100 / [Total Actual Income])

I tried creating two measures one for the selected property code, year and month which gives me amount of each field for the property I select.
Did the same thing but added one more condition for line no. 24 which gives me amount of total actual income.
tried both of them separately and then dividing them and tried both of them into one function.
Separately it works perfect, just that I do not get any output for all the line.
Instead get only for one line.


Try these measures:
TotalActualIncome
TotalActualIncome = CALCULATE(
    SUM(OnePage[Amount]),
     FILTER(ALL(OnePage), OnePage[GL] = "Total Actual Income") //Makes sure the OnePage table is not fitlered prior to the calculation
     )

PercentageMeasure
PercentageMeasure = 
VAR TAI = [TotalActualIncome]
VAR TotalSelectedAmount = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Onepage[Amount]),
        ALLSELECTED(OnePage[GL]) //Used GL instead of PropertyCode since I don't have this column in my sample data. 
    )
    RETURN 
    DIVIDE(TotalSelectedAmount, TAI)*100

